# Having Issues with npm

Tags: javascript, npm-scripts

> ```
> npm ERR! missing script: start
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Earnest\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06->05T12_21_01_507Z-debug.log
> ```

and the Script is there.
I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run the command `npm start`
where as in your `package.json`, it is missing. Trying putting this in your `package.json`

`"scripts” :{ “start” : ...}`

Comment: Sir i have the sent code in the package.json "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./server.js"
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"

Comment: so not if you run the command `npm run start` --> this will be equivalent to running `node ./server.js`

Comment: am having this after trying it severally please help out:

Comment: $ npm run start
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file C:\Users\Earnest\Desktop\git.show\package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 243 while parsing '{
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "name": "git.show",
npm ERR! JSON.parse   "version": "1.'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

Comment: Looks like your `package.json` is corrupt. Can you show me the file?